# How do I put this differential equation into mathcad 11

Tags: calculus, math-software, mathcad

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+\frac{dy}{dt}+2y(t)=sin(t)+2e^{-2t}-2$$

I want to put this into mathcad, and then solve it numerically.

I would also like to plot the solution.

Sorry for the link, wasn't sure how else to put it nicely on here.

Comment: I do have access to mathematica too.

Comment: Many thanks man. My initial conditions would be y=1 and dy/dx=0 when t=0. The range would be t=0 and t=10

Comment: Hmm ok, for me it's coming up with this error "is incomplete; more input is needed." what do kind sir?

Comment: Thanks for your patience too